# How to subscribe to subcollection in Flutter Firebase Messaging?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on notifications for my Flutter application. I have read the documentation, but could not find solution to my problem. I want to subscribe to subcollections and with Firebase Functions send the notification if something changes in subcollection.

Let me clarify the situation more clearly. I have several users in my application and I have managed to setup subcollections for messaging. So, for each user there is /users collection and messages subcollection. I want to subscribe to /messages subcollection to get changes with Firebase Functions.

The code for Firebase Functions in Typescript is like this:

```
functions.firestore.
    document("users/{userId}/messages/{messageId}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      console.log(snapshot.data());
      console.log(snapshot.data());

      return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("users", {
        notification: {
          title: snapshot.data()["username"],
          body: snapshot.data()["text"],
          clickAction: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        },
      });
    });
```

However, I don't know how to subscribe to subcollection in Flutter side (to subscribe to collection we use `FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('users');`).

Is there any way to achieve this? I want to detect if there are changes in subcollections for each user.

Comment: There is no concept of collections or subcollections in Firebase Cloud Messaging, all it has is a flat list of topics. This sounds very much like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish with this Cloud Function (not the implementation, but the use-case)?

Comment: I want to subscribe the users to /users/{userId}/messages collection where in Firestore messages is called subcollection of users collection. I want to subscribe single user messages and from Cloud Functions I want to send notification to user as he subscribe to /users/{userId}/messages collection. Hope I explained it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no concept of collections or subcollections in Firebase Cloud Messaging, all it has is a flat list of topics.

So you will have to come up with your own mapping of the subcollections to unique topic names, for example by having both the document IDs in there: `users_<userId>_messages_<messageId>`. With such a structure, you users can subscribe to that specific topic, and your server-side code can send to the same topic with something like:

```
functions.firestore.
    document("users/{userId}/messages/{messageId}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      console.log(snapshot.data());
      console.log(snapshot.data());

      return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(
        `users_${context.params.userId}_messages_${context.params.messageId}`, {
        notification: {
          title: snapshot.data()["username"],
          body: snapshot.data()["text"],
          clickAction: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        },
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This now makes sense. In Flutter, I have to use collection to subscribe, not the document, right? I mean you wrote users_<userId>_messages_<messageId> but it has to be users_<userId>_messages to subscribe in Flutter side.

Comment: I didn't really understand your use-case, so copied pretty literally what it says in your question into the topic. But if you want to "simply" target each user through a topic, you can use only the `users_${context.params.userId}` part in the topic. Note that topics are not private, so with this scheme you could subscribe to someone's messages if your know their UID, which might be OK or not in your use-case.

Comment: This might make sense, but what about ```document("users/{userId}/messages/{messageId}")```, without knowing the userId here, is it possible to detect the messages subcollection?

Comment: Yes, the Cloud Functions declaration you have listens to all `messages` subcollections of all users.

Comment: Hey @FlutterDev Anything else needed here?

Comment: Thank you so much Frank. This solved my issue. By customising the code you suggested, I achieved notifications working good. I accepted your answer.